# Формат даты php

Tags: php

Как дату `2019-02-15 23:01:51` вывести в таком формате d.m.Y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью DateTime:

```
echo DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2019-02-15 23:01:51')->format('d-m-Y');
```

Или так:

```
echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime('2019-02-15 23:01:51'));
```